# I'm trying to set up apcupsd on a raspberry pi to communicate with a tripp-lite power supply

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to get this to work.  I have:

- Raspberry Pi B (I think) running Raspbian 10 (buster)
- Tripp Lite OMNI1500LCDT
- Connection via USB

I have the following configuration files:

/etc/apcupsd/hosts.conf:

```
MONITOR 127.0.0.1 "Local Host"
```

/etc/default/apcupsd

```
ISCONFIGURED=yes
```

/etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf:

```
UPSNAME triplite
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE
```

When I run sudo apctest (note that I stopped the daemon first) I get:

```
apctest
2020-04-04 00:28:18 apctest 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian
Checking configuration ...
sharenet.type = Network & ShareUPS Disabled
cable.type = USB Cable
mode.type = USB UPS Driver
Setting up the port ...
apctest FATAL ERROR in apctest.c at line 321
Unable to open UPS device.
  If apcupsd or apctest is already running,
  please stop it and run this program again.
apctest error termination completed
```

when I run sudo /etc/init.d/apcupsd start, the log looks OK:

```
Apr  4 00:29:57 megabyte systemd[1]: Starting UPS power management daemon...
Apr  4 00:29:57 megabyte systemd[1]: apcupsd.service: Can't open PID file /run/apcupsd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Apr  4 00:29:57 megabyte apcupsd[6712]: apcupsd 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian startup succeeded
Apr  4 00:29:57 megabyte apcupsd[6712]: NIS server startup succeeded
Apr  4 00:29:57 megabyte systemd[1]: Started UPS power management daemon.
```

When I run lsusb I get (note that the Tripp Lite UPS is listed on Device 4:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Glide
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 09ae:3016 Tripp Lite
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: This is routine challenge for sysadmin and many of them could answer such question. But sysadmins do not track StackOverflow. I think you will get more chances for the answer at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up installing nut by following [these directions](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/5ssb5h/ups_server_on_raspberry_pi/) and now nut is working fine.